# Call classmethod in class constant

Tags: python, python-3.x

I send a object over a socket and want to know the size of the object as bytes. I write a method return the object as bytes. At the receiver side a have to know the size of the object so I import the class and want to use a constant. To define the constant I wrote a classmethod who return the length in bytes but i can´t call the classfunction in the class themself. The size of the object can by change while developing the project and thats why i dynamicly what to calc the uses size.

```py
class democlass():

    BYTE_SIZE = democlass.get_byte_size()

    def __init__(self, t: int):
        self.data = t

    def as_bytes(self) -> bytes:
        """
        Some struct.pack() stuff.
        """
        return objectasbytes

    @classmethod
    def get_byte_size(cls) -> int:
        return len(democlass(5).as_bytes())
```

```py
import democlass


class server(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, t: int):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.__sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        addr = (
            '0.0.0.0',
            self.port
        )
        self.__sock.bind(addr)

    def run(self) -> bytes:
        while True:
            msg = sock.recv(democlass.BYTE_SIZE)
            do_something_withdata()
```

Errormessage:

```
BYTE_SIZE = democlass.get_byte_size()
NameError: name 'democlass' is not defined
```

Comment: please fix your indentation, also you cannot do `BYTE_SIZE = democlass.get_byte_size()` inside the class `democlass`, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Same, usually I'm pretty good at guessing what people *intent* to write, but in this case, I'm completely clueless.

Comment: Are you thinking of the `@property` decorator?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply. I try to explain: I have a object I want to send over a socket. I am still working an this object so I don`t know the size every time i test my code. So I try to dynamicly get the size by making a dummy object, convert it to bytes and return the lenth of the bytes. I want to know the size for the socket.recv() so i only receive as many bytes as i nee

Comment: Aaah, now it makes a little more sense. How do you serialize that object? Instead of writing a wrapper around the class that determines how big it is, I would write a serialize function and a constructer that re-creates that object from the serialized byte-string, then you can just send the byte-string as a packet.

Comment: I think you are primarily using `recv()` wrong, the parameter is *NOT* how many bytes you want to receive, but how many bytes you want to *maximally receive at once*. In SOCK_STREAM, your packages can always get split into multiple parts. In SOCK_DGRAM just specify some value that is definitely larger than the size of your message, and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Finomnis I have a classmethod wich makes an object by the bytes send over the socket, thats not the problem. But I want to make sure I only receive a full object and no more other data.

Comment: @MarLei you won't, on SOCK_DGRAM. recv will return exactly as many bytes as you sent. DGRAM is package-based, not stream-based. You will always receive exactly the entire package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot construct an instance of a class until it is fully defined. Move the definition of the "constant" to just after the class definition and attach it to the class explicitly and this will work, while still behaving identically:

```
class democlass():

    def __init__(self, t: int):
        self.data = t

    def as_bytes(self) -> bytes:
        """
        Some struct.pack() stuff.
        """
        return objectasbytes

    @classmethod
    def get_byte_size(cls) -> int:
        return len(democlass(5).as_bytes())

democlass.BYTE_SIZE = democlass.get_byte_size()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here

1) When you call get_byte_size() first, it doesn't exist yet. Execution is top to bottom, so it's not been defined.

2) Even if you moved it, the class wouldn't exist. It's a method of the class, so the class needs to be finished creation before the class methods exist.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing your code, I think you are doing things more complicated than necessary, and I'd like to offer you a simple server-client object serialization example.

This is the class we want to send:

```py
# We will use json for (de-)serialization here,
# but you can use whatever you want
import json

# An example class that holds a string and an integer
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, msg, number):
        self.msg = msg
        self.number = number

    @staticmethod
    def deserialize(data):
        json_str = data.decode('utf-8')
        data = json.loads(json_str)
        return MyClass(data[0], data[1])

    def serialize(self):
        data = [self.msg, self.number]
        json_str = json.dumps(data)
        return json_str.encode('utf-8')

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyClass("' + self.msg + '", ' + str(self.number) + ')'
```

Now here is the client that sends the package:

```py
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

server_address = ('localhost', 12345)

obj = MyClass("Hello world!", 42)
sock.sendto(obj.serialize(), server_address)
```

And here is the server that receives the object:

```py
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

server_address = ('localhost', 12345)
sock.bind(server_address)

data = sock.recv(4096)
obj = MyClass.deserialize(data)

sock.close()

print(data)
print(obj)
```

Output of the server:

```
b'["Hello world!", 42]'
MyClass("Hello world!", 42)
```

I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I have a reason why I implement my serialisation by my own. I implement a prototype protocol for a vehicle2infrastructure service. This is designed for 10 million messeges per secound. So every bit I save at this UDP Message saves network capacity and resources. I only have to send bits I realy need.

Comment: I really don't wanna argue with you if necessary, but I kind of have to reply to this :) The serialization is not the point here. You can serialize however you want. All I wanted to say is that you don't NEED to know the size of your structure, it is pointless to compute it. At the *sender* side you just have the entire message. and on the *receiver* side, you don't the size of the message, you just have to specify a buffer that is large enough. Speed wise, having that receive buffer be a power if two is most likely faster.

Comment: Additionally, if you want **that** kind of throughput, python is the wrong language. C, C++ or Rust would be the appropriate choices.

Comment: Yes you are right that I don´t need to know the size of the received data but why shoud I receive more data as I need? I will round up the value to the next power of two. Yes Python is the wrong language for this project but prescribed.

Comment: You don't receive more data than needed. You receive exactly that data, specifing a larger number in 'recv' doesn't actually make you receive more data. Whether you specify exactly the number you receive or a huge number, the transmitted data will be exactly the same.

Comment: I think you should look a bit deeper in the difference between the TCP, UDP and IP protocols. Then you will realize that UDP already transmits size information for you, whether you want it or not. Computing it extra is not necessary.